# Vim improperly highlights "very magic" and "very nomagic" regular expressions

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

I'm editing a `.vim` syntax file in vim itself, and I'm using "very magic" and "very nomagic" regexes, simply because I think they make more sense. Unfortunately, vim does not in any way highlight these correctly. For example, this regex, using very nomagic:

```
/\V[/
```

should match an open bracket. Unfortunately, vim thinks this is an unterminated collection, and so it floods the file with purple highlighting until it finds the next `]`.

Is there any way to get vim to properly highlight these regular expression modes?

Comment: Where exactly are you using this pattern? If this is for syntax highlighting, please read the bit about `magic` and `cpoptions` under [`:help syn-pattern`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:syn-pattern).

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to override some of the default `syntax/vim.vim` syntax definitions (in `~/.vim/after/syntax/vim.vim`), because the syntax doesn't consider this case, and assumes the default `'magic'` regular expression syntax.

I guess the author of this syntax, Chip Campbell, didn't want to further complicate the (already quite large) syntax, and avoid the increased testing effort. It's certainly a good idea to ask him about including support for the `\V` / `\M` atoms, or whether he at least would accept a patch to include such an enhancement.